# How to downcast an object that can be of multiple types?

Tags: ios, swift, casting, anyobject

Apple gives us an example of downcasting an object of the same type as such:

```
let someObjects: [AnyObject] = [
    Movie(name: "2001: A Space Odyssey", director: "Stanley Kubrick"),
    Movie(name: "Moon", director: "Duncan Jones"),
    Movie(name: "Alien", director: "Ridley Scott")
]
```

We can then access each individual attribute by creating an abstract variable "object" and casting it as what we expect it to be (a movie) :

```
for object in someObjects {
    let movie = object as! Movie
    print("Movie: '\(movie.name)', dir. \(movie.director)")
}
```

But what if we go to the next level and for example we have subclasses of movies:

Silent films

Comedy

Action

Each of which all have the same attributes - name & director

I've tried to cast it the same way we did above as a "Movie" since I assumed as a parent class, it would be able to recognize its subclasses, but of course this has not worked otherwise this question would not have existed!

Comment: Can you show the code, how you tried to cast the subclasses in the same way?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. It works fine when I try it (not that this is a good idea. You shouldn't need `AnyObject` very often, and you should generally avoid subclasses and down-casting if you can avoid them.) As ronatory notes, you should show the code that *doesn't* work, rather than just the code that *does*.

Comment: Don't forget to come back and accept an answer or vote on the answers that helped you.

Comment: Have you tried using `as?` instead of `as!`

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question right. So the cast works the same way with the subclass as in your example. Maybe you missed something (Hints are in the code comments):

```
// here the subclass SilentFilm
class SilentFilm:Movie {

}

// Here the array with SilentFilm objects
let someOtherObjects: [AnyObject] = [
    SilentFilm(name: "silentname", director: "silentdirector"),
    SilentFilm(name: "silentname2", director: "silentdirector2")
]

for object2 in someOtherObjects {
    // Here the cast to Movie like in your example
    let movie = object2 as! Movie
    // or cast to SilentFilm works also
    // let movie = object2 as! SilentFilm
    print("Movie: '\(movie.name)', dir. \(movie.director)")
}

// Expected Output
// Movie: 'silentname', dir. silentdirector
// Movie: 'silentname2', dir. silentdirector2
```

Correct me if I missunderstood your questions!

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a class hierarchy with a parent `Movie` class and check the type of the movie while iterating through your array?  There is no need to force cast from `AnyObject` if you specify your array contains `Movie` objects, and have all of your sub-genres inherit from `Movie`.

```
class Movie {
    var name: String!
    var director: String!
    
    init(name: String, director: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.director = director
    }
}

class Comedy: Movie {
    var laughTrack: Bool!
    
    init(name: String, director: String, laughTrack: Bool) {
        super.init(name: name, director: director)
        self.laughTrack = laughTrack
    }
}

let someObjects: [Movie] = [
    Movie(name: "2001: A Space Odyssey", director: "Stanley Kubrick"),
    Movie(name: "Moon", director: "Duncan Jones"),
    Movie(name: "Alien", director: "Ridley Scott"),
    Comedy(name: "Caddyshack", director: "Harold Ramis", laughTrack: false)
]

for movie in someObjects {
    if movie is Comedy {
        print("\(movie.name) is a comedy")
    } else {
        print("\(movie.name) is a movie")
    }
}
```

Output:

> 2001: A Space Odyssey is a movie
>
> Moon is a movie
>
> Alien is a movie
>
> Caddyshack is a comedy